# href and click both in knockout

Tags: knockout.js

Assume 'CustomerTab' to be dynamic href build using some function. I have created a function which is called on the click of href. Problem it is not
going to the designatied href after the click event is raised. Even though i return true value from the function it does not seem to be working.

```
<a data-toggle="tab" title="Menu Setup" aria-expanded="true" data-bind="attr:{href:CustomerTab}, event : {click : $root.CustomerTabClick.bind(CustomerTabContent) }">Customer</a></li>
```

Please let me know for any help

Answer (score 1):

You should not have a click event on a link element. Change it to another element. and redirect to the url with window.location.replace("someURL") in your customerTabClick function after running whatever other logic this function contains. If you are just adding a hash to the url use window.location.hash = "someURL" insted

Comment: <a data-toggle="tab" id="CustomerTab" title="Menu Setup" aria-expanded="true" data-bind="attr:{href:CustomerTab}"> <span data-bind="event : {click : $root.CustomerTabClick.bind(CustomerTabContent) }">Customer</span></a>

Comment: i have added the span tag and the click event is invoked. since the href already has a dynamic url . But the dynamic url is not working once the click event is fired.

Comment: @jaiganesh It won't the `<span>` click doesn't ever trigger the `<a>` click, they are two separate elements. As @joonas89 said, you should include a `window.location = CustomerTab` into your click event.